# Ajax.ActionLink confirm message is being displayed twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

i have the following ajax.actionlink

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "order",

        new { id = order.OrderID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = "are you sure to perform the deletion.",
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              UpdateTargetId = order.OrderID.ToString(),
              LoadingElementId = "Progress"
          })
```

but when i click on the delete link; the confirm message "Confirm = "are you sure to perform the deletion."" will be displayed twice one before calling the action method and one after.
so what might be the problem?
currently i am using the following scripts inside the view

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Edited:-**   i remove all the duplicated scripts and i ended up with only these scripts but the problem still there:-
i ended up with only these scripts ,, but the problem still there

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly, and you don't need jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js included on the page at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could be because you're referencing the same libs more than once.

```
jQuery.tmpl.js 
jQuery.tmpl.min.js 

jquery-1.6.2.min.js
jquery-1.6.2.js

jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js //Three times!
```

They're the same lib although one is just [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29). Try cleaning up your lib references, that will fix your issue of the message being displayed twice.

Comment: i removed most of the scripts ,, (see my edit in my original question) ,, but the problem is still there. BR

Answer (score 0):

*Two* mistakes might cause such kind of **problems:**

1. make sure the View page you render be a partial page such as (_Delete) on above ajax call.
2. you must have executed the Jquery unobtrusive-ajax script twice in your project.